# Use bloomRpc for protobuf request

Tags: kotlin, grpc, protobuf-java, bloom

I have a field defined in protobuf as
`map<string, google.protobuf.Value> configurations = 1`

But when I try to test the code and call the grpc API through bloomRpc, I'm having trouble to correctly construct the field in bloomRPC, seems for google this field, it has 'kind' and corresponding value, so if I want to update the value, it needs to be

`"config_extensions": { "ext1": { "kind": "stringValue", "stringValue": "Custom value 1" }, "ext2": { "kind": "numberValue", "numberValue": 42 }, "ext3": { "kind": "boolValue", "boolValue": true } },`

But I need a listValue, so when I put the 'kind' as 'listValue' and use 'listValue':[] I got an error as 'an array is needed', but when I use listValue: {"value": {}} this also cannot be recornigzed as list..

How can I properly construct a bloomrpc (or json?) value for the protobuf request ..

I tried
"config_extensions": {
"ext1": {
"kind": "stringValue",
"stringValue": "Custom value 1"
},
"ext2": {
"kind": "numberValue",
"numberValue": 42
},
"ext3": {
"kind": "boolValue",
"boolValue": true
}
},
but not sure how to construct 'listValue' here